# Using streams how can I create a summary object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

Please assume I have the following data structure

```
public class Payment {
    String paymentType;
    double price;
    double tax;
    double total;

    public Payment(String paymentType, double price, double tax, double total) {
        super();
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
        this.price = price;
        this.tax = tax;
        this.total = total;
    }
    public String getPaymentType() {
        return paymentType;
    }
    public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public double getTax() {
        return tax;
    }
    public void setTax(double tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
    }
    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

In another method I would have a collection built of that type as follows:

```
private Payment generateTotal() {
    Collection<Payment> allPayments = new ArrayList<>();
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type1", 100.01, 1.12, 101.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type2", 200.01, 2.12, 202.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type3", 300.01, 3.12, 303.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type4", 400.01, 4.12, 404.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type5", 500.01, 5.12, 505.13));

    //Generate the total with a stream and return

    return null;
}
```

I would like to stream these to map to a total object

i.e.

A payment object that looks like this

```
paymentType = "Total";
price = sum(payment.price);
tax = sum(payment.tax);
total = sum(payment.total);
```

I know I can do this with mapToDouble one column at a time, but I would like to use a reduce or something to have this happen in one stream.

Comment: What's the added value of doing it with a Stream? what you want can be easily achieved with a for/foreach loop. We shouldn't use streams for the sake of using streams. We use streams/lambdas to make our life easier not harder...

Comment: Sorry - just typed fast to get the idea out there.  Updated with code that compiles.

Comment: Streams are easier to read, and understand what is going on.

Comment: **wrong**. Streams *can* be easier to read in certain scenarios. Streams are not a silver bullet...

Comment: Write a Collector, or make three passes on the stream, to compute the three sums.

Comment: I've just stumbled across this blog post and thought it may be interesting: https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/08/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops-by-stream-foreach/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use streams for this, but since you asked:

```
    Payment total =
            allPayments.stream()
                    .reduce(
                            new Payment("Total", 0, 0, 0),
                            (sum, each) -> new Payment(
                                    sum.getPaymentType(),
                                    sum.getPrice() + each.getPrice(),
                                    sum.getTax() + each.getTax(),
                                    sum.getTotal() + each.getTotal()));
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was looking for.  Appreciate the pointer on the reduce.

Comment: @purringpigeon it's a good answer but what's the added value, in your case, of reducing? if it was over thousands of objects and you'd use `.parallel` that would be a good reason, otherwise, I like alfasin's answer better...

Comment: For my current implementation this solution provides the clarity that I needed.  Also when I think functional programing, I think about side effects - so in alfasin's answer he is causing a side effect while in the lambda.

Comment: What's the "side effect" that is caused by the answer that I submitted and which is not present here ? this solution creates a new Payments object upon every iteration, while the solution I suggested creates only one additional object which is used as the accumulator...

Comment: The side effect is that you are effecting an object outside the iteration, in the solution above everything is handled within the iteration.  When I took the lambda classes (and the stream sessions at Java One) from Oracle they recommend against using a foreach( p -> {}) to update variables outside the iteration.

Comment: @purringpigeon I believe you're taking something you've read/heard outside its context. What you just wrote in your last comment probably happens in 99.99... percent of the for-loops you'll see in Java...

Comment: I agree this is used a lot.  At the last JavaOne they used this type of example and recommended a reduce instead of creating a place holder object and updating from within the forEach(p->{}).  It was done at one of their Engineering sessions.  So I am just trying to follow their recommendations.  Both work fine.  It was stated that the forEach() is probably the most misused API in collections.

Comment: @purringpigeon such a recommendation should have a reasoning behind it. The reasoning provides the context of when you should follow this advice and when not. Following any advice blindly without understanding the reasoning behind it is not recommended. As I wrote: there are no silver bullets and any rule of thumb should be reconsidered any time you want to apply it.

Comment: @alfasin: the difference is simple; the `reduce` solution can run in parallel, the `forEach` solution can not. If this is not a concern, as this seems to be a more academic question, then the OP is right, `reduce` is an FP solution, the `forEach` solution is not. This doesn’t make your solution incorrect (it’s worth noting that there is a difference between `Stream.forEach` and `Collection.forEach`), as an ordinary `for` loop isn’t an FP solution either, but still correct. And simple. [An efficient Stream/FP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779238/2711488) has to sacrifice simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement your own `Collector` to a `Payment` object:

```
Payment total =
    allPayments.stream()
               .collect(Collector. of(
                   () -> new Payment("Total", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (Payment p1, Payment p2) -> {
                       p1.setPrice(p1.getPrice() + p2.getPrice());
                       p1.setTax(p1.getTax() + p2.getTax());
                       p1.setTotal(p1.getTotal() + p2.getTotal());
                   },
                   (Payment p1, Payment p2) -> {
                       p1.setPrice(p1.getPrice() + p2.getPrice());
                       p1.setTax(p1.getTax() + p2.getTax());
                       p1.setTotal(p1.getTotal() + p2.getTotal());
                       return p1;
                   }));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use Streams where it's shorter and easier to read something like:

```
    Payment sum = new Payment("Total", 0, 0, 0);
    allPayments.forEach(p -> {
        sum.price += p.price;
        sum.tax += p.tax;
        sum.total += p.total;
    });
```

As discussed in the comments, this solution is not only shorter and cleaner (IMO) but also easier to maintain: for example, say that now you have an exception: you want to continue summing all these attributes but you want to exclude the item on the second index. How easy will it be to add it to a reduce-verion vs a simple for-loop?

What's also interesting is that this solution has a smaller memory footprint (because reduce creates an additional object every iteration) and runs more efficiently with the provided example.

Drawback: the only one I could find is in case the collection we're processing is huge (thousands or more), in that case we should use the reduce solution with Stream.parallel but even then it should be [done cautiously](https://dzone.com/articles/think-twice-using-java-8)

Benchmarked with JMH in the following way:

```
@Benchmark
public Payment loopIt() {
    Collection<Payment> allPayments = new ArrayList<>();
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type1", 100.01, 1.12, 101.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type2", 200.01, 2.12, 202.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type3", 300.01, 3.12, 303.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type4", 400.01, 4.12, 404.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type5", 500.01, 5.12, 505.13));
    Payment accum = new Payment("Total", 0, 0, 0);

    allPayments.forEach(x -> {
        accum.price += x.price;
        accum.tax += x.tax;
        accum.total += x.total;
    });
    return accum;
}

@Benchmark
public Payment reduceIt() {
    Collection<Payment> allPayments = new ArrayList<>();
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type1", 100.01, 1.12, 101.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type2", 200.01, 2.12, 202.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type3", 300.01, 3.12, 303.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type4", 400.01, 4.12, 404.13));
    allPayments.add(new Payment("Type5", 500.01, 5.12, 505.13));
    return
        allPayments.stream()
            .reduce(
                new Payment("Total", 0, 0, 0),
                (sum, each) -> new Payment(
                    sum.getPaymentType(),
                    sum.getPrice() + each.getPrice(),
                    sum.getTax() + each.getTax(),
                    sum.getTotal() + each.getTotal()));
}
```

**Results:**

```
Result "play.Play.loopIt":
  49.838 ±(99.9%) 1.601 ns/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (43.581, 49.838, 117.699), stdev = 6.780
  CI (99.9%): [48.236, 51.439] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:07:36

Benchmark    Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
Play.loopIt  avgt  200  49.838 ± 1.601  ns/op
```

---

```
Result "play.Play.reduceIt":
  129.960 ±(99.9%) 4.163 ns/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (109.616, 129.960, 212.410), stdev = 17.626
  CI (99.9%): [125.797, 134.123] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:07:36

Benchmark      Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
Play.reduceIt  avgt  200  129.960 ± 4.163  ns/op
```

Comment: This is a good, thorough answer. A couple of thoughts: 1. It's often recommended to make value-like objects immutable (notable examples: Integer, BigInteger, java.time classes). If Payment was immutable, you wouldn't be able to use it as an accumulator as in loopIt(). You would instead have to create a new Payment in each iteration, which you do anyway in reduceIt(). 2. About half of the time in your methods is spent creating the list of Payments. You would see a much bigger difference between the two methods if you initialised the list once and passed it as an argument to both methods.

Comment: By the way, reduce doesn't *have* to create an additional object in every iteration; it's just highly recommended to avoid mutations, but you could, if you wanted, use accum in reduceIt() the same way you use it in loopIt(). Similarly, you could create a new Payment each time in the forEach loop. There are two orthogonal concepts here: (1) immutability vs accumulation; and (2) looping vs reducing. You could mix and match between them independently.

Comment: 1/2 @KlitosKyriacou good points! I'd just add that with reduce I don't see an easy way to go without creating new objects (assuming you can't change the Payments you're iterating on - which is a valid assumption). The foreach approach's advantage is that it can easily support both cases (mutability and immutability) without creating new object per iteration by saving the accumulations into local variable, again, something that you'll have to work hard to achieve with reduce. Now I don't want to sound like I'm against using reduce in general, it's just that I've seen developers abuse streams

Comment: 2/2 and lambdas more than a few times, that I developed an allergic reaction :) lambdas and reduce are great for expressive 1 or 2-liners. But when we have to write more complicated code that is harder to read, understand and maintain - it beats the purpose.

Comment: Indeed. Write code because it's clearer, not because it uses newer features. By the way, I think with reduce you can create accum initialised with zeros outside the call, and then call `reduce(accum, (sum,each)->{sum.price+=each.price;...;return sum;})` (since we know sum is actually accum). This is not the way you're supposed to use streams and it's probably not guaranteed to work, and it probably won't work with parallel streams.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `BinaryOperator<Payment> accumulator` for combining two `Payment`s:

```
public static Payment reduce(Payment p1, Payment p2) {
    return new Payment("Total", 
            p1.getPrice() + p2.getPrice(), 
            p1.getTax() + p2.getTax(), 
            p1.getTotal() + p2.getTotal()
    );
}
```

and the reduction will look like:

```
Payment payment = allPayments.stream().reduce(new Payment(), Payment::reduce);
```

or (to avoid identity object creation):

```
Optional<Payment> oPayment = allPayments.stream().reduce(Payment::reduce);
```